# Bokeh server example not working

Tags: python, bokeh

I wanted to get familiar with Bokeh and went through the examples. However, when I try to run the crossfilter example as explained on this website (https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/app/crossfilter), I get the following error message:

```
$ bokeh-server --script crossfilter_app.py




Bokeh Server Configuration
==========================
python version : 2.7.10
bokeh version  : 0.9.3
listening      : 127.0.0.1:5006
backend        : memory
python options : debug:OFF, verbose:OFF, filter-logs:OFF, multi-user:OFF
js options     : splitjs:OFF, debugjs:OFF

adding  to python path
importing crossfilter_app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "//anaconda/bin/bokeh-server", line 7, in <module>
bokeh.server.run()
File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/server/__init__.py", line 188, in run
start_server(args)
File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/server/__init__.py", line 192, in start_server
start.start_simple_server(args)
File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/server/start.py", line 52, in start_simple_server
configure_flask(config_argparse=args)
File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/server/configure.py", line 76, in configure_flask
imp.load_source("_bokeh_app", script)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Could someone please help me out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to update to at least Bokeh version `0.11` which is when the new (much improved) Bokeh server was introduced. Then, navigate to the directory that has the `crossfilter` subdirectory, and run:

```
bokeh serve --show crossfilter
```

Note, `bokeh-server` is the ***old*** Bokeh server, from versions `0.10` and earlier. It has been deprecated and removed entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You must run that command in a directory that contains the file `crossfilter_app.py`, or (assuming you have a copy of the file somewhere on your computer) give the full path to `crossfilter_app.py`.  If you don't have it, you can download it from the github page.